# cross-platform apps with c#Is

Tags: java, c#, android

This is a question isn't asking whether is't possible (because I've already checked that) but as too way it's generally frowned upon.

My background in programming is C and C# and I've been more interested in app development since the announcement of Windows 10. I have also been interested in Android development for some but don't have the time to really dwell into Java. I do know however that C# can be used to write applications for Windows and Android so sticking wit C# seems all the more compelling.

Looking at the new Visual Studio RC, I notice that they are saying that you'll be able to run native android apps using C#. However, of this forum it's apparent that people don't like the idea of using another language other than Java to do so. Would there even be such a performance drop when many android devices have quad-core SoC's with 2-3GB RAM? I'm really intrigued in using C# for cross-platform development the Windows platform is interesting me even more.

**As I should state, I'm already aware of Xamarin cross-platform development. But this question is specifically on the performance difference and the fairly mute enthusiasm by many android devs when suggesting so.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# and Java are pretty close langues so that is why the conversion from C# to Java is easier. Based on your code and the approaches you follow, the performance of course is to change, however, as mentioned since C# and Java are syntactically very close it will just be converted to the Java code and compiled using Process Virtual Machine. The only difference would how Java and C# takes same code block, and compiles it. I think you will just need to research that point, and then you should be safe to go.

Comment: So as long as my C# code is written correctly, that should minimalise the performance gap with the same code written in Java? Xamarin say that they use Just-intime (instead of the current ahead-of-time runtime which is of course faster), but from my understanding a code written in C# isn't going to RAM hogging app that feels super sluggish (as long as I approach everything precisely of course).

Comment: That is correct. Even though the compilation logic, and the binary codes a bit different, the approaches are similar, therefore if the best approaches followed in C#, it is highly likely that your code will be optimized when the conversion occurs. The only thing to watch out would be the Java performance tips. As an example, Arraylist maybe much slower than Array in Java, but List and Array have similar speeds in C#. So in that case, I would rather use Array instead of List.

Answer (score 0):

You will need [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/platform) if you want to use C# to develop Android apps. Xamarin claims "native performance".

Comment: I already know that you can use Xamarin, but what performance difference is there really? And why is it not seen as a viable alternative to Java code?

Comment: @KristopherRahimAfful-Brown Seen as a *viable alternative* by whom? You can't go on a forum and take the general opinion of one discussion board as basis for an assumption of a *viable alternative.* Just because person A doesn't like it (because it's not native, or what-have-you), doesn't mean it's not a *viable alternative.* Have you used it yet? Have you benchmarked either? If not, then you don't know which is a *viable alternative.* I suggest you benchmark the performance of each before questioning further.

Comment: The performance will never equal true native performance, but it can be pretty close because it recompiles instead of interprets the C# code. It all depends on what you're doing. There is no way to know how it will perform for your app until you try it. The main reason you'd use it is if you're a C# programmer looking to develop cross-platform apps. If all you want is an Android app, it will be easier to stick with Java and Android Studio.

Comment: So only when wanting to go cross-platform, is using C# acceptable in short? Picking up another language (as much as people proclaim it's better solution) isn't much of an option for me as this is only a past-time for my studies as an EEE student (where C, C++ and C# are more widely used)

Comment: In my opinion, the difficulty of using cross-platform frameworks like Xamarin is underrated. Just because it allows you to use C#, that doesn't mean you don't still have to learn the Android (or iOS) APIs, which Xamarin bridges. And if you want to learn those, using Java (or Swift) will be a lot easier than using C#. You might end up spending a lot more time on it than if you had used Java (or Swift) in the first place.